# How to rebind AltGr+a to \ with xmodmap?

Tags: linux, xmodmap

My keyboard has one less key than my layout, so I have to improvise.

I'd like to bind <kbd>AltGr</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> to backslash "\" instead of "æ", and <kbd>AltGr</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd> to pipe "|" instead of "ß". How can I do so using xmodmap (or any other program a user can configure)?

Answer (score 1):

`xmodmap -pke` lists the configuration of the current layout. I had to add the following lines to my `.xmodmap` file

```
keycode 38 = a A a A backslash AE ae
keycode 39 = s S s S bar section ssharp
```